# I pushed api key to public repository in github

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, cloud, credentials, api-key

**Yes, i did it.**
What amaze me is that bots are scanning github for searching free api keys. And i can understand that, but what is weird. They were able to activate different api (compute engine) host 3 virutal machines and use it to mine crypto.
A question is, isn't it vulnerabilty that they can host virtual machines and use different api ?
I had to shut down whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the role assigned to compromised service-account - attacker can do everything or nothing.

There are some basic "[best practices](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-iam-securely#service_accounts_and_service_account_keys)" regarding keys and [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#best_practices) that should be usefull to you.

Generally use (if possible) different service account to manage VM's or/and rotate keys weekly or twice a week (just like the Google-managed ones) and avoid putting any API keys into repositories that can/will be synchronised with public ones :)

Yes - sounds silly but slip-up's happen and this will make unathorised access way less likely or impossible.

Also fallowing "[least privilege](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-iam-securely#least_privilege)" rule may be worth going for - compromised credentials will not be much usefull then.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, since Aug. 2021:

> ### [Secret scanning org-level REST API](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-24-secret-scanning-org-level-rest-api/)
>
> GitHub Advanced Security customers can now retrieve private repository secret scanning results at the organization level via the GitHub REST API.
> This new endpoint, in beta, supplements the existing repository-level endpoint.

The API is: [`GET /organizations/:organization_id/secret-scanning/alerts`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/secret-scanning).
See "[About secret scanning for private repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-scanning/about-secret-scanning#about-secret-scanning-for-private-repositories)"

In your case, querying that new (still beta) API endpoint can be a good practice, to be alerted *before* an attacker has time to do much damage.

---

And this is also for public repositories!

> ### [Secret scanning is now available for free on public repositories](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-12-15-secret-scanning-is-now-available-for-free-on-public-repositories) (Dec. 2022)
>
> Previously, only organizations with GitHub Advanced Security could enable secret scanning's user experience on their repositories.
> Now, any admin of a public repository on GitHub.com can detect leaked secrets in their repositories with GitHub secret scanning.
>
> The new secret scanning user experience complements the [secret scanning partner program](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/secret-scanning-partner-program), which alerts over 100 service providers if their tokens are exposed in public repositories.
> You can read more about this change and how secret scanning can protect your contributions in our blog post.
>
> - [Read our blog post to learn how you can secure your public repositories…for free](https://github.blog/2022-12-15-leaked-a-secret-check-your-github-alerts-for-free)
> - [Learn how to secure your repositories with secret scanning](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-scanning/about-secret-scanning)